# Is it possible to see list of customers in App Store Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect, apple-id

We have an iOS app and we sell in-app purchases. Is it possible to see individual customers or purchase events via app store connect or some other admin tool?

This is possible with admin dashboards for Stripe and Paypal (completely different products, I know) and I believe this may be possible for Google Play in-app purchases, but I can find no way to see anything except aggregated stats for iOS in-app purchases.

Why: We're currently troubleshooting a bug where some IAPs are not syncing to our internal systems, and we're trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: This thread from 3 years ago suggests the answer is No: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/68487

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to see individual customer information in App Store Connect. You cannot see the details of a single purchase event in order to connect that for example to an internal system based on customer email, account number or similar.